# My Vaadin Login Page doesnt trigger Chromes "Save Password" function

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-chrome, firefox, vaadin

I am currently working on a website written with Vaadin and Spring Security.

When you login to a webpage, e.g. Mail Clients etc you get the "Do you want to save your password" prompt. In my case this is not happening.

I have created a vaadin application which doesnt trigger this.

I do have a form with action and method and also have named my inputs correctly.

I tried enabling autocomplete and autocorrect=off but it doesnt seem to work. Any reason why this doesnt get triggered?

Additional information:

Vaadin Version: 14.1.17
Spring Boot: Latest Version

URL to test: https://rp.mainlevel.at

Code:

```
username = new TextField();
username.getElement().setAttribute("name", "username");
username.setAutocomplete(Autocomplete.USERNAME);
username.setAutocorrect(false);
username.setPlaceholder(getTranslation("login.username", langLocale));
username.addClassName(AdminPress.FORM_CONTROL);

pwfield = new PasswordField();
pwfield.getElement().setAttribute("name", "password");
pwfield.getElement().setAttribute("id", "password");
pwfield.setAutocomplete(Autocomplete.CURRENT_PASSWORD);
pwfield.setAutocorrect(false);
pwfield.setPlaceholder(getTranslation("login.placeholder.password", langLocale));
pwfield.addClassName(AdminPress.FORM_CONTROL);
```

Comment: Please share the code of your login view. without it, we cannot know what you may be missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Code is added. I thought it was more helpful seeing the page itself. Here are the two code snippets that are relevant for the fields.

Comment: The input element in the TextField and PasswordField are hidden inside these web-components shadow DOM, hence Chrome is not detecting the native input normally and this autocomplete does not happen.

Comment: There is also feature request about this in Chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input element in the `TextField` and `PasswordField` are hidden inside these web-components shadow DOM, hence Chrome is not detecting the native input normally and this autocomplete does not happen. There is also [feature request](http://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649162) about this in Chrome

There is a [Login form component](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/) in the framework which should work with with password managers. On Vaadin web site there is also a [detailed tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/java-web-app/login-screen) how to use it with Spring Security as well.

Comment: Any workaround for this? Otherwise I just Put the feature request to my watchlist...

Comment: there exists [this workaround](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17399734/17613155) (putting the input elements into the light DOM), but i don't know if it works with your own login form.